# runtime error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter

Tags: java

Get this runtime error when generating jwt token:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64Codec.encode(Base64Codec.java:21)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64UrlCodec.encode(Base64UrlCodec.java:22)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.base64UrlEncode(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:349)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.compact(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:295)
```

Any ideas what is the issue? Tried to change jdk version: 9 and 14 behave the same.

Comment: The error message tells you what is wrong. The class is not found in the classpath

Comment: Base64Codec.class: public String encode(byte[] data) {
        return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(data);
    } and what can not be found here?

Comment: the error says it couldn't find the `DatatypeConverter` class which means it's not in the classpath. Either you have a mismached version of jar in your path or the jar is missing entirely. You need to figure out what jar that class should be in and add it to your classpath

Comment: Thank you. I found a solution in this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j   Had to add <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency> to my pom.xml